# warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

New to C, I have this function:

```
void getNum(int *n) {
  scanf("%d", &n);
}
```

And in main:

```
int main() {
  int someNum;
  getNum(&someNum);
  return 0;
}
```

Where exactly does the 'int **' part of this error come from, and are there other issues with how I'm passing things around?

Comment: You use an `&` in front of a plain `int` to convert it into an `int *`.  Here, you already have an `int *` because it is an output argument to your function, so you don't need the `&` (any more than you put an `&` in front of an array).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only problem is passing `&n` to scanf: `n` is already a pointer, and so your `scanf` call is passing a pointer to that pointer, hence the warning.

Use: `scanf("%d", n);`